# How to prevent Macro from returning to Gosub

Tags: asterisk

I'm using Asterisk. Here is my scenario:

```
[my-custom-ivr]
exten => s,1,Background(fa/main_menu)
exten => 1,1,Gosub(ghesse-sub,s,1(1))

[ghesse-sub]
exten => s,n,Macro(get-subfolder,${ARG1})
exten => S,n,Read(digitsDetected,"barg/1-Ghesseh/GhesseMenu/1",1,,2,10)
exten => s,n,NoOp(${digitsDetected});
exten => s,n,Macro(get-storyfilename,${digitsDetected})
exten => s,n,Playback(${StoryFileName})
exten => s,n,NoOp(${MaxStoryID})
exten => s,n,NoOp(${StoryFolderID})
```

After executing Macro(get-subfolder,${ARG1}) it goes back to Gosub(ghesse-sub,s,1(1)). How to prevent it from doing that?

Comment: please provide trace of call and output of command "dialplan show ghesse-sub"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the desired behavior of GoSub (execute a subroutine and then continue where you left off).

If you don't want this behavior, then you should be using Goto instead.

Comment: You can find this note in Asterisk documentation. It says that stackpop() should be used to prevent this behavior. How should I use this command?